# Foreach loop isn't working for expanding user entered text

Tags: php, arrays, forms, foreach, nested-loops

I have a textarea in which users write like this:

- 3x Blue Flower
- 2* Red Flower
- 5 Purple Flower
- Yellow Flower

The point is to echo Blue Flower 3 times etc., while flowers that don't have numbers are echoed 1 time.

This is my code:

```
$str = $_POST['tekst'];
$input = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($input as $line)
{
    preg_match("/\d+/", $line, $matches);
    $line = preg_replace("/\d+/",'' ,$line);
    $number = (isset($matches[0]))?$matches[0]:1;
    if(strlen($line)>0){
        foreach ($line as $k=>$val)
        {
            $temp_second_field = $number[$k];
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $temp_second_field ; $i++ )
            {
                echo $val;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: get a `var_dump()` from `explode("\n", $str);` and check whether you have predicted result or not

Comment: Should be `echo htmlspecialchars($val);`

Comment: `array (size=2)
  0 => string '3 Blue Flowers
' (length=14)
  1 => string '5 Purple Flowers' (length=16)`
i got error that there is an invalid argument in second foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because $line is not an array, it is a string. Try replacing this :

```
// foreach ($line as $k=>$val)
// {
    // $temp_second_field = $number[$k];
    // for ($i = 0 ; $i < $temp_second_field ; $i++ )
    // {
        // echo $val;
    // }
// }
//$temp_second_field = $number[$k];
```

with this:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $number ; $i++ )
{
    echo $line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think, second foreach:

```
foreach ($line as $k=>$val)
```

is a mistake - are you try iterate over string by symbol?

look at this code:

```
$str = $_POST['tekst'];
$input = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($input as $line)
{
    preg_match("/\d+/", $line, $matches);
    $line = preg_replace("/\d+/",'' ,$line);
    $number = (isset($matches[0]))?$matches[0]:1;
    if(strlen($line)>0){
        echo str_repeat( $line."\n", $number );
    }
}
```